# How to generate XSLT 3.0 templates from a yaml file?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, yaml, xslt-3.0

I'm trying to find a way to generate xslt 3.0 templates from a yaml file and i'm looking for a way or a tool that can help me do it, the yaml file contains the list of transformations, here is the yaml file :

```
transformations:
  - element: ABC
    action:
      removeElement: true
  - element: BCD
    action:
      removeElement: true
  - element: OldName1
    action:
      renameTag: NewName1
  - element: OldName2
    action:
      renameTag: NewName2
      changeAttributes:
        - name: x
          value: '@H'
        - name: y
          value: '@V'
        - name: PI
          value: 3.14
      excludedAttributes:
        - H
        - V
```

i'm already parsing the yaml file to my java objects using snakeyaml

```
@Data
public class Transformations {
    private List<Transformation> transformations;
}
@Data
public class Transformation {   
    private String element;
    private Action action;
}
@Data
public class Action {
    private String renameTag="";
    private boolean removeElement=false;
    private List<Attribute> changeAttributes= new ArrayList<>();
    private boolean copyOtherAttributes=true;
    private List<String> excludedAttributes= new ArrayList<>();
    private String addChildElement="";
    private String copyAttributesIn="";
}
@Data
public class Attribute {
    private String name;
    private String value; 
}
```

i have passed the transformations list to my xslt 3.0 file

```
List<Transformation> transformationList = transformations.getTransformations();
transformer.setParameter("list", transformationList);
```

then i create a new class, implemented ExtensionFunction and used saxon and s9api in order to create all the getters for theses classes to use them in xslt

here is how i looped through the list and used the getters to print some attributes :

```
<xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="$list">
            <xsl:variable name="item" select="."/>
            <Tranformation>
                <xsl:variable name="element" select="ext:getTransformationAttribute('element',$item)"/>
                <xsl:variable name="actionObj" select="ext:getTransformationAttribute('action',$item)"/>

                <xsl:value-of select="$element" /> 
                <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$actionObj" />

                <Action>
                    <xsl:variable name="renameTag" select="ext:getTransformationAttribute('renameTag',$actionObj)"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$renameTag" />
                    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:variable name="removeElement" select="ext:getTransformationAttribute('removeElement',$actionObj)"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$removeElement" />
                    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:variable name="changeAttributes" select="ext:getTransformationAttribute('changeAttributes',$actionObj)"/>
                    <xsl:for-each select="$changeAttributes">
                        <xsl:value-of select="." /> 
                    </xsl:for-each>

                    <xsl:variable name="addChildElement" select="ext:getTransformationAttribute('addChildElement',$actionObj)"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$addChildElement" />
                </Action>
                <!-- 
                    <xsl:value-of select="$item"  />
                -->
            </Tranformation>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```

what i want to do now is to generate the xslt templates by theses attributes in order to transform my xml file using yaml, one problem is that i cannot call template inside another template or inside if tag or choose tag

example of templates which i need generate :

```
<xsl:template match="Element">
        <NewName2 x="{@H}" y="{@V}" PI="3.14">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(name() = ('H', 'V'))]" />
            <addedChild>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
            </addedChild>
        </NewName2>
</xsl:template>
```

in some transformations i have to add a child element, some should exclude attributes from copy, some don't have a renameTag action, some should have their attributes copied in the child tag and so on..

here is how it can be done with java for example :

```
private static void generateXSLT(String xsltPath, Transformations transformations) throws IOException {

    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(xsltPath);
    StringBuilder xslt = new StringBuilder();
    xslt.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n"
            + "<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\"\n"
            + "    xmlns:xs=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"\n"
            + "    xmlns:math=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math\"\n"
            + "    xmlns:xd=\"http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl\"\n"
            + "    exclude-result-prefixes=\"xs math xd\" version=\"3.0\">\n");
            // strip-space is used for removing empty lines after deleting some elements
            // template to copy everything
            xslt.append("<xsl:strip-space elements=\"*\" />\r\n" + "    \r\n" + "    <xsl:template match=\"/\">\r\n"
            + "        <xsl:apply-templates />\r\n" + "    </xsl:template>\r\n" + "    \r\n"
            + "    <xsl:template match=\"*\">\r\n" + "        <xsl:copy>\r\n"
            + "            <xsl:apply-templates select=\"@* | node()\" />\r\n" + "        </xsl:copy>\r\n"
            + "    </xsl:template>\n\n");
    List<Transformation> transformationList = transformations.getTransformations();
    for (Transformation transformation : transformationList) {
        if (action.isRemoveElement()) {
            xslt.append("\t<xsl:template match=\"" + xpath + "\"/>\n");
        } else if (action.getRenameTag() != null) {
            xslt.append("\t<xsl:template match=\"" + xpath + "\">\n");
            if (action.getChangeAttributes() != null) {
                xslt.append("\t\t<" + action.getRenameTag());
                for (Attribute attribute : action.getChangeAttributes()) {
                    xslt.append(" " + attribute.getName() + "=\"{" + attribute.getValue() + "}\"");
                }
                xslt.append(">\n");
            } else {
                xslt.append("\t\t<" + action.getRenameTag() + ">\n");
            }
            if (action.getExcludeAttributes() != null) {
                xslt.append("\t\t\t<xsl:apply-templates select=\"@*[not(name() = (");
                if (action.getExcludeAttributes() != null) {
                    xslt.append("\t\t\t<xsl:apply-templates select=\"@*[not(name() = (");
                    for (String excludedAttribute : action.getExcludeAttributes()) {
                        joiner.add("'" + excludedAttribute + "'");
                    }

                    xslt.append(joiner.toString() + "))]|node()\"/>\n");
                } else {
                    xslt.append("\t\t\t<xsl:apply-templates select=\"@*|node()\"/>\n");
                }
                

                xslt.append("\t\t</" + action.getRenameTag() + ">\n");
                xslt.append("\t</xsl:template>\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see your XSLT code generation any XSLT although your title suggests that is (part of) what you want to achieve. As for: " i cannot call template inside another template or inside if tag or choose tag": why is that?  `<xsl:template name="foo"><xsl:call-template name="bar"/></xsl:template>` is perfectly possible and not constrained. You can't nest template declarations but calling or applying templates at any level inside of another template is possible. Thus, if you have concrete code giving a concrete error, share that code.

Comment: Don't try to explain what you want to achieve by including code in comments. Edit your question to show any code there, in a well formatted way. To me it is not clear why you need both Java classes and XSLT code to generate XSLT code, it seems, XSLT code should suffice to process YAML and generate XSLT code. Anyway, it is not clear at which point you struggle so that someone could help fix a well defined and isolated problem; it seems you have chosen some complex task which might need some complex solution. But you have not even specified what your YAML stands for in terms of XSLT.

Comment: in my project i need to use xslt to transform an xml to xml, but i need to add a new layer in order to simplify the work, instead of making xslt templates everytime i want to specify the transformations in a yaml file then generate the xslt templates from it, so simply YAML contains the list of transformations for each element.
"XSLT code should suffice to process YAML and generate XSLT code." 
can you tell me how, any useful links please ?

Comment: YAML is a text format, you can read it in with e.g. `unparsed-text('foo.yaml')`, you can process it with all text processing features you have in XSLT 3 (i.e. `analyze-string`, `tokenize`, grouping, matching) to transform it to maps/arrays or XML and then process that further. Whether it is in the end easier to have someone write YAML to have a transpiler to to create XSLT instead of having people write XSLT directly (e.g. `<xsl:template match="ABC"/>` seems to be what your `-element: ABC action: removeElement: true` amounts to) I doubt. It all depends on the skill sets of people involved.

Comment: yeah it depends on the skills sets of the people involved and that's why i'm asked to do generate xslt templates from YAML, and i think you gave me a better solution, i think i better transform it to XML and then process it further
Thanks a lot @MartinHonnen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple example to transpile part of your YAML to XSLT and then run it in XSLT 3 is at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiZNCwk doing e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:axsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform-alias"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
  
  <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="axsl" result-prefix="xsl"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="yaml-as-xslt" as="element(xsl:stylesheet)">
      <axsl:stylesheet version="3.0">
        
        <axsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
        
        <xsl:for-each-group select="tokenize($yaml, '\n') => tail()" group-starting-with=".[matches(., '^\s+-\selement:')]">
          <axsl:template match="{substring-after(., 'element: ')}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[3]"/>
          </axsl:template>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
        
      </axsl:stylesheet>
    </xsl:variable>
    
    <xsl:sequence
      select="transform(map { 'source-node': ., 'stylesheet-node' : $yaml-as-xslt})?output"/>  
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match=".[matches(., '^\s+renameTag:\s')]">
    <axsl:element name="{substring-after(., 'renameTag: ')}"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match=".[matches(., '^\s+removeElement:\strue')]"/>

  <xsl:param name="yaml" as="xs:string" expand-text="no">transformations:
  - element: ABC
    action:
      removeElement: true
  - element: BCD
    action:
      removeElement: true
  - element: OldName1
    action:
      renameTag: NewName1
  - element: OldName2
    action:
      renameTag: NewName2</xsl:param>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to transform e.g.

```
<Root>
  <ABC/>
  <BCD/>
  <OldName1/>
  <OldName2/>
</Root>
```

based on the YAML rules into

```
<Root>
   <NewName1/>
   <NewName2/>
</Root>
```

Of course the full meaning of your YAML specifying XML transformations is not given and I have not tried to guess it for all of your sample nor have I tried to implement all of the sample, in the end, as said in the comment, an additional step first transforming the YAML into an intermediary XML or maps/json data structure to then generate XSLT and execute is might be necessary for a complex YAML syntax to define XML transformations.